# Why is there a syntax error when the left operand of the exponentiation operator is negative?

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, exponent, ecmascript-2016

When I use the exponent operator (`**`) in JavaScript, it normally works as expected:

```
2 ** 2   // 4
2 ** -2  // 0.25
```

But when the left operand is negative

```
-2 ** 2
```

I get a syntax error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token **

I can get around it easily by putting parentheses around `-2`

```
(-2) ** 2 // 4
```

but I'm curious about what caused this error. Other operators (`+ - * / %` etc) don't have this problem. Why does this happen for the `**` operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is intentional and is there to prevent you from writing ambiguous expressions. [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Notes):

> In most languages like PHP and Python and others that have an
>   exponentiation operator (**), the exponentiation operator is defined
>   to have a higher precedence than unary operators such as unary + and
>   unary -, but there are a few exceptions. For example, in Bash the **
>   operator is defined to have a lower precedence than unary operators.
>   In JavaScript, it is impossible to write an ambiguous exponentiation
>   expression, i.e. you cannot put a unary operator
>   (+/-/~/!/delete/void/typeof) immediately before the base number.
>
> ```
> -2 ** 2; 
> // 4 in Bash, -4 in other languages. 
> // This is invalid in JavaScript, as the operation is ambiguous. 
>
>
> -(2 ** 2); 
> // -4 in JavaScript and the author's intention is unambiguous.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Interesting. I did find some documentation on Mozilla which specifies why that's impossible.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation

2 ** -3 is possible, though.